In Euler's rotation theorem, does the fixed point need to be on the rigid body?
My understanding of Euler's rotation theorem from Wikipedia is that when a rigid body moves while a point on the rigid body stays fixed (the fixed point), then the motion is equivalent to a rotation around an axis that goes through that point.
It seems plainly clear that the fixed point is on the rigid body. However, when I read the Mechanical Engineer's Handbook by Marghitu, in Section 4.4 (page 98), it states Euler's Theorem as:

A rigid body constrained to rotate about a fixed point can move between any two positions by a single rotation about some axis through the fixed point.

It doesn't mention that the fixed point has to be on the rigid body. The book proceeded to derive rigid body motion as consisting of rotations around instantaneous axes of rotations. The figures in the book (4.5, 4.6) has the fixed point be on the body, but somehow the book doesn't give a definition of what "fixed point" means.
Is it just inaccuracy of the book's writing?  Or, is Wikipedia's statement of Euler's rotation theorem less general?

The thrust of Euler's theorem stems from the fact that any transformation (whether active or passive) in the form of a 3d rotation around the origin, leaves a particular family of vectors unchanged. Intuitively speaking, these are ones that point in the direction of the axis of rotation. More specifically, these are eigenvectors of the rotation matrix.
Now a historical note of import, is that Euler's original theorem was specifically about spheres in particular. You can find the original version translated to English in the article you've linked to. So on the face of it, it is less general than both Wikipedia's and the book's versions. However, I believe Euler used the simplest case of the sphere, while knowing that therein lies a much more general point.
The more general point is that we can always fix our coordinate origin at some point along the axis of rotation of the rigid body. In such a frame, any initial state of the body is related to any final state by a single rotation around said axis.
Yes, it's a simple matter to generalize the above also to cases where the rotation is about an axis that lies outside of the rigid body. But I think in fact the book is being rather confusing on that account in stating:

A rigid body constrained to rotate about a fixed point can move between any two positions by a single rotation about some axis through the fixed point.

(Emphasis mine).
Because, "any two positions" is rather vague here. When discussing Euler's theorem, we typically consider some initial and final orientations of the body (specified, for instance, via Euler angles), which also kind of implies we're mainly interested in rotation axes that pass through the rigid body itself. Anyway, whether we want to discuss positions or orientations, we need to have some coordinate system with respect to which we specify them, but in the part you've quoted there's no mention of which coordinate system the "positions" are expressed in.
If the coordinate system is assumed to be one where the origin lies on the axis of rotation (incidentally, this can also be a point outside of the rigid body, but that's a minor detail here), things become simple, but they really should mention this explicitly if that's the case. Even here, we must specify the additional caveat that the body is going through a pure rotation. We didn't have to specify that condition when we assumed a coordinate system that's fixed to the body. Because, any overall translational motion of the body is by definition not measured in a coordinate system that's fixed to the body.
To explain better why I say that the specification of the coordinate system is important, see the following capture I've taken from a Geogebra demonstration:

A rotation around a fixed axis is always in some plane. We imagine then that the rotation axis is going "out of the screen" here. What I wanted to demonstrate, is that in one coordinate system the origin is $\mathcal{O}_1$, so any pair of blue position vectors corresponding to the initial and final positions of the "body" (the point describing the circle) in that coordinate system are related by a single rotation. However, that's not the case for the red position vectors as given by a coordinate system with origin $\mathcal{O}_2$, as is immediately apparent.
Nevertheless, it is correct that if you allow the rigid body to purely rotate in a "floating manner" around some fixed axis that doesn't pass through it, again the vectors pointing in the direction of that fixed axis remain unchanged by the action of the rotation, and the initial and final state of the body can be related by a single rotation if we choose our origin to lie on the axis of rotation.
So, I suppose you can say that the book is more general at least on account of allowing the rotation axis to lie outside the body. But as I said previously it is also quite ambiguous with regards to what coordinate system we're supposed to assume here.
You may want to compare with treatments of the theorem by more well-known texts like Goldstein's, and perhaps that can help you get a better idea of the theorem (I think Wikipedia does a decent job in this case, too).

Yes, "any positions" is indeed another confusing part of that statement. It leaves too much to the imagination of the reader. Thanks for the reference of the textbook!

I reflected on my question and the book's statement. If the fixed point isn't on the rigid body, the theorem would be false (I can translate the body along a straightline to or away from the fixed point; that wouldn't be a rotation).  The motion of the rigid body and the fixed point are completely independent entities.

You're welcome @zkytony. Note that as I tried to explain, it is possible to give meaning to Euler's rotation theorem for axes that lie outside the body if we confine ourselves to only consider pure rotations around the given axis. Then it is still correct that any initial and final "state" (better word than position) that can generated by such a rotation, is given by a single rotation (matrix). It is actually equivalent to imagining we extend the rigid body by an imaginary rod, that's perpendicular to the rotation axis, which starts at the origin and terminates on the rigid body.

It does seem to me however it kind of misses the point of the theorem to include such cases. One of the main uses of the theorem is the observation that, we can treat the rotational motion of the body separately from the translational motion. So that the overall motion can always be described via these two independent pieces.

Of course. I wasn't arguing to include those cases in the theorem. But basically, the book's statement is wrong (even if we ignore the phrase "any position").

@zkytony Well, they do write "constrained to rotate", so if we want to be generous we can assume that "constrained" also means it isn't allowed to "translate away" from its current radius of rotation :) but I agree, on the whole this phrasing is rather poor and too open to interpretation.

@zkytony See my edit, I added an illustration to explain why I think the main problem with the phrasing is the lack of specification of a coordinate system.

Thanks for the effort. I'll mark this as resolved.
